# Possible bug in RegionUnion or related functions?

Tags: bugs, regions, mesh

**Bug introduced in 11.2.0**

---

Functions for derived geometric regions (`RegionUnion` and related) have been significantly updated in MMA 11.2 and now this simple example doesn't work any more as expected. Could this be a bug or I am using the functions in the wrong way?

```
d[radius_Real] := Disk[{0, 0}, radius];
r[size_Real] := Rectangle[-{size, size}, {size, size}]

$Version
Region[
 RegionUnion[
  RegionDifference[r[4.], r[3.]],
  RegionDifference[d[2.], d[1.]]
  ],
 ImageSize -> 200,
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

In version 11.1.1 I get the expected region shape.
[image: version_11.1.1]

And this is result of version 11.2. Also `ToElementMesh` fails to create a mesh from this region. (However, it does work if I replace the arguments of `r` and `d` with exact numbers.)

[image: version_11.2]

Comment: I think it is a bug ...

Comment: Wolfram Technical support confirmed that this is a bug ([CASE:3952103]).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a bug.

Notice that applying `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to your region shows an error:

> BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::defbnds: Unable to compute bounds for the region. Using default bounds of {-1, 1} in all dimensions.

Trying `RegionBounds` on it returns no result.

This explains the strange output.

However, changing `RegionDifference[d[2.], d[1.]]` to `Region@RegionDifference[d[2.], d[1.]]` "fixes" the problem. Now everything works fine.

`Region` does not seem to change the structure of `RegionDifference[d[2.], d[1.]]`.

My conclusion is that this might be a bug. I would not expect different results when `Region` is or isn't used, only perhaps different performance (as `Region` is able to do certain checks *a single time*, and then guarantee that whatever it contains is a correctly defined region).

I suggest you report this to Wolfram Support.