# Unable to discretize a union of primitives

Tags: graphics3d, regions, mesh, rendering

I am using MMA 11.0.1.0, tested on both Ubuntu 64-bit and Windows 10 64-bit. The documentation has a nice example with a capsule:

[image]

Both plotting and explicit discretizing works perfectly, the code is

```
capsule = 
  RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}, 1],
    Ball[{2, 0, 0}, 1]];
RegionPlot3D[capsule, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 40]
DiscretizeRegion@capsule
```

However, when I make a union with more of the same objects (`Ball` and `Cylinder`), I run into problems. Consider this pipe network:

```
capillaryRadius = 0.000012; (*m *)
zCoord := 0.0000864;
node1 = {-0.000212, -0.000151, zCoord};
node2 = {-0.0001655, -0.0002305, zCoord};
node3 = {-0.0000835, -0.000044, zCoord};
node4 = {-0.0000225 , -0.000093, zCoord};

nodePrimitives = 
  Ball[#, capillaryRadius] & /@ {node1, node2, node3, node4};
segmentPrimitives = 
  Cylinder[#, capillaryRadius] & /@ {{node1, node3}, {node1, 
     node2}, {node2, node3}, {node3, node4}, {node2, node4}};
Graphics3D[{Red, nodePrimitives, segmentPrimitives}]
```

[image]

So far these are just separate objects. Now let us form a `RegionUnion` and repeat the same things we did with the capsule:

```
network = RegionUnion@Join[nodePrimitives, segmentPrimitives];
RegionPlot3D[network, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
DiscretizeRegion@network
```

Unfortunately `RegionPlot3D` plots an empty box and `DiscretizeRegion` returns this error message:

```
DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region RegionUnion[<<9>>].
```

Note that `DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@nodePrimitives` works fine, but `DiscretizeRegion@RegionUnion@segmentPrimitives` returns the same kind of error message as above, something must be up with those cylinders!

Bug reported to Wolfram CASE:3983297.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with version 11.2 after you have replaced

```
network = RegionUnion @ Join[nodePrimitives, segmentPrimitives]
```

by

```
network = RegionUnion @@ Join[nodePrimitives, segmentPrimitives]
```

Because I can only use Version 11.2 in the cloud, I had to limit `PlotPoint` to 50. The result is then :

[image]

This works too :

```
DiscretizeRegion @ network
```

[image]

I confirm that `RegionPlot3D` and `DiscretizeRegion` don't work on 11.0 (neither with @ nor @@)

Otherwise it seems that :

- `RegionUnion` accepts both syntaxes @ and @@ in version 11.0
- `RegionUnion` only accepts @@ in version 11.2

Comment: Something related : One interesting progress in 11.2 is that `RegionUnion` works with `MeshRegion`, for example : `RegionUnion @@ (DiscretizeRegion /@ {Cuboid[],Cuboid[{0.5,0.5,0.5}]})` is OK. The impossiblity to apply `RegionUnion` on `MeshRegion` in 11.0 is documented. See the doc RegionUnion -> Possible issues

Comment: Thank you! Will do my best to get 11.2 from my Uni asap.

Comment: Any thoughts on a possible workaround for 11.0.1.0? It will be a while until I get access to 11.2, and I need to be able to do `DiscretizeRegion @ network` sooner.

Comment: @AlexanderErlich I don't have any solution and I'm rather pessimistic because I have played several hours with this kind of thing on version 11.0. in the past (I don't remember the details). Even version 11.2 isn't very polished (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157031/5467) for example)