# RegionUnion Polygons different online than desktop

Tags: regions, mathematica-online, version-11.3

I have been trying to use Mathematica online and a function operates differently I think incorrectly online.

```
RegionUnion[
  Polygon[{{26.9194,75.7986},{26.9035,75.8145},{26.8975,75.8122},
           {26.8982,75.7876},{26.9025,75.7816}}],
  Polygon[{{26.9105,75.8057},{26.8905,75.8147},{26.8946,75.7834},
           {26.9035,75.7879},{26.9194,75.7986},{26.9181,75.7999}}]
 ]
```

results in

```
Polygon[{{26.8995, 75.7859}, {26.9025, 75.7816}, 
         {26.9194, 75.7986}, {26.9181, 75.7999}, 
         {26.9035, 75.8145}, {26.8975, 75.8122}, 
         {26.8975, 75.8115}, {26.8905, 75.8147}, 
         {26.8946, 75.7834}}]
```

which I believe is correct. But results in

```
BooleanRegion[#1||#2&,
  {Polygon[{{26.9194,75.7986},{26.9035,75.8145},{26.8975,75.8122},
            {26.8982,75.7876},{26.9025,75.7816}}],
   Polygon[{{26.9105,75.8057},{26.8905,75.8147},{26.8946,75.7834},
            {26.9035,75.7879},{26.9194,75.7986},{26.9181,75.7999}}]}]
```

which is in its unevaluated form. My Desktop `VersionNumber` is 11.2 whereas the online `VersionNumber` is currently 11.3.

Is this an issue with the latest version or with the online version? Problem raised with Wolfram [CASE:4052183]. It arrived at version 11.3.

Comment: It doesn't work too on my Mathematica 11.3 desktop. But good new : The solution proposed by @Szabolcs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157033/5467) works.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand how the solution identified above helps.

Comment: Did WRI confirmed or did you only send a report so far? Btw, can you show an example where it matters that the result is kept in symbolic BooleanRegion form? As long as it works like region should, it is not a bug. Or is there a statement that `RegionUnion` should evaluate to a specific form? Sorry if I missed your point.

Comment: Both results are fine. It's possible to compute with the boolean region form `b`, so that `Region[b]`, `Area[b]` etc. work as expected. You can get a polygon result by something like `MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[b, MaxCellMeasure -> 1], 2]`

Comment: Based on @ilian 's confirmation I removed bugs tag. Ilian, do you mind posting an authoritative answer?

Comment: @NigelKg what is the source of your claim that it is a bug? Please do not revert changes I've made untill it is settled.

Comment: @Kuba My initial impression was wrong. While the new form of the result isn’t incorrect, it also isn’t intended. The simpler result would be better in this case, and I am told it has been restored in one of the development branches.

Comment: @ilian Still, from user's perspective it is not a bug and it is better not to expect anything specific from RegionUnion. Unless documentation is not complete there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question ilian provided the answer and also gave me insight. I still consider this to be a bug because the behaviour changed considerably.

It seems that the behaviour of RegionUnion in 11.2 is not what was intended and so the bug is in 11.2. Interestingly the bug only occurs with real numbers in the Polygon points. If the Polygon points are integers then the 11.2 and 11.3 behaviour is the same. The documentation in 11.3 does not say that the behaviour changed in 11.3, it only says that it was updated in 11.2.

I had not appreciated that my use of `RegionUnion` in 11.2 was unpredictable behaviour. Where two intersecting polygons produced a `Polygon`. This behaviour only seems to happen when any of the points in either `Polygon` has a `Real` rather than an `Integer` as one of its points.

```
a = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
b = Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}];
c = RegionUnion[a, b]
d = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[c, MaxCellMeasure -> 1], 2]
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], a, b, Green, d}]
```

It seems that this is now robust to 11.2 and 11.3 whether or not there are integers in the points.

```
c gives BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {
                      Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
                      Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}]}]
d gives {Polygon[{{-0.5,0.5},{-1.,0.},{0.,0.},{1.,0.},{0.5,0.5},
                  {1.,1.},{0.,1.},{-1.,1.}}]}
```

The graphic is as expected. (I will add the graph when I can!)

Comment: `RegionUnion` should produce a region or fail. You should not expect a neat solution for edge cases as long as the result is valid for region calculations.